# fancybox and onfocus

Tags: fancybox, textarea

I need to load fancybox with inside php file, when I will click on textarea.

My code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#mypop").click(function() {
        $.fancybox({
        'href'                  : 'file.php',
        'transitionIn'      : 'none',
        'transitionOut'     : 'none',
        'titleShow' : false,
        'overlayColor'  :   '#fff',
        'overlayOpacity':   0.8 }); });</script>

<textarea rows="4" cols="50" onfocus="#mypop" ></textarea>
```

Why this is not working ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your textarea tag: remove `onfocus="#mypop"` and add `id="mypop"`. The `$("#mypop")` function-call will search for an element with `id="mypop"`, and the `click(function(){...})` function will add the event-listener. This function-call also makes the `onfocus=`-attribute unnecessary.

Comment: Thank you I forgot to add before $("#mypop").click(function() to add $(document).ready(function() :) now it works!

Comment: Ok but what will be with Submit button ? What will I need to write in input onclick ?

Comment: I don't actually know anything about fancybox, so I can't give you any specific advise. But if it has an element on the page it displays when needed (as opposed to creating it using Javascript). Then you can look up the id of the submit-button and add your send-function as an event-listener to it.

Answer (score 0):

`<script type="text/javascript">`
    `$("#mypop").click(function() {`
          `$.fancybox("<iframe src='file.php' frameborder='0'></iframe>",`{
                `maxWidth : 700,`
                `maxHeight    : 600,`
                `fitToView    : false,`
                `width    : '50%',`
                `height    : '50%',`
                `autoSize : true,`
                `closeClick: false`
          `});`
      `});`
`</script>`
`<textarea rows="4" cols="50" id="mypop" ></textarea>`

By: Jose ALfredo Cocom Chan